# Getting incompatible pointer type warning because the return of the function is not void* but a struct pointer

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers, gcc-warning

This warning seems to not be necessary.
In my code, I have a function pointer type

`(void*)(*function_pointer)(void* data)`

and some functions require function pointers of this type as a parameter, because they do not depend on the return type, it just has to be a pointer.

But, when I pass a function like `somestruct* function_A(void* data)`
to it, I get that warning, even though `somestruct*` could be implicity converted to `void*`, the same way that I can pass to a function `int function_test(void* data)` a `somestruct` pointer and it would work without warnings.

Yes I can define `function_A` with a `void *` as return type, but it would mean everyone who will use that function for other reasons will have to cast its return value to `somestruct *`.  I have these two options: leave as it is and ignore the warning which annoys me a bit, or change the function definition, which would annoy me even more.

So here I am, asking if there is a third option.

Comment: It’s `void*(*function_pointer)(void* data)`: you can’t put parentheses around the `void*` at the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is allowed to convert any object pointer to a `void *` and back, however that does not carry over to arguments and return types in function pointers.

A pointer to function `somestruct* function_A(void*)` is not compatible with a function pointer of type `void* (*function_pointer)(void*)` because the return types are not compatible.  Attempting to call a function through an incompatible pointer type will trigger [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The rules regarding how to determine if two function types are compatible are spelled out in section 6.7.6.3p15 of the [C standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> **For two function types to be compatible, both shall specify compatible
> return types.** Moreover, the parameter type lists, if both are
> present, shall agree in the number of parameters and in use of the
> ellipsis terminator; corresponding parameters shall have compatible
> types. If one type has a parameter type list and the other type is
> specified by a function declarator that is not part of a function
> definition and that contains an empty identifier list, the parameter
> list shall not have an ellipsis terminator and the type of each
> parameter shall be compatible with the type that results from the
> application of the default argument promotions. If one type has a
> parameter type list and the other type is specified by a function
> definition that contains a (possibly empty) identifier list, both
> shall agree in the number of parameters, and the type of each
> prototype parameter shall be compatible with the type that results
> from the application of the default argument promotions to the type of
> the corresponding identifier. (In the determination of type
> compatibility and of a composite type, each parameter declared with
> function or array type is taken as having the adjusted type and each
> parameter declared with qualified type is taken as having the unqualified version of its declared type.)

The portion in bold is what's relevant in this particular case.  A `void *` and and struct pointer are not compatible, even though it's allowed to convert between the two.

The rules of function pointer conversions are spelled out in section 6.3.2.3p8:

> A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a
> function of another type and back again; the result shall compare
> equal to the original pointer. **If a converted pointer is used to call
> a function whose type is not compatible with the referenced type, the
> behavior is undefined.**

With the last section in bold stating that what you're attempting to do is not allowed.

You'll need to change the return type of your function to `void *` to be compatible with the function pointer type.  Casting the return type however is not necessary, as conversions between an object pointer and a `void *` is allowed without one.

Answer (score 1):

A `void *` isn't a necessarily the same size as a `somestruct *` or returned the same way. Your code has undefined behaviour.

You need to provide a function that returns a `void *`. It's fine if it's a `somestruct *` that's been converted to a `void *` (through an implicit or explicit cast), but it needs to be a `void *`.

You could do this by passing a wrapper that handles the conversions.

```c
somestruct *function_A( somestruct* );

void *voided_function_A( void* p ) {
   // Short for `return (void *)function_A( (somestruct *)p );`.
   // These casts produce the necessary code to convert the pointers.
   return function_A( p );
}

typedef void *Function( void* data );

Function *function_pointer = voided_function_A;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can’t use a function pointer of type `int(*)(long)` where one of type `long(*)(int)` is required, even though the argument and the return value could be converted without loss if information, because a caller of a function pointer of the latter type cannot know to adjust the **calling convention** so as to successfully call a function of the former type.

For situations like this, you just add a **wrapper** of the correct type:

```
somestruct* function_A(void* data);
void* voided_A(void *p) {return function_A(p);}
```